# How do I download Ubuntu and get rid of my old os?

Tags: installation, usb-drive, delete

I have a net book with Windows 7 Starter and I downloaded Ubuntu on my usb drive, since I don't have a disk drive. And I want to install it and delete windows all at the same time, because I don't think it will have the processing capacity to to have both at the same time. Anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would just do a normal USB boot and then there is an option when installing ubuntu to either do a dual boot or delete the other OS completely.

Answer (score 1):

If for "processing capacity" you mean CPU & RAM, then you don't need to wipe Win7. You can install Ubuntu in another(s) partition(s) of the hard disk in what is called a *dual-boot* system: each time you start your netbook you will have the option to boot one **or** the other OS, so resources won't be shared (and more limited). That is definitely the best option if you want to try/use Ubuntu but still need Win7 and your CPU&RAM are scarce (an usual alternative is to run one of them as a virtual machine inside the other but then you will be sharing those scarce resources).

I would not call it "processing capacity", but if what you mean is hard disk space, then yes, you will need to share that in a dual-boot scenario (Win7 takes much more minimum disk space, and while Ubuntu can access Win7 filesystem, the other way round is, at least, more difficult). In this case, maybe installing Ubuntu **instead** of Win7 Starter will make better use of your limiting resources.

You will have both options available when you boot from the bootable USB Ubuntu installer (install Ubuntu keeping or replace Win7).